# How to access the values in the text variable of widget spinbox in tk?

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

This is my command for spinbox:

```
    spinbox .mytopframe.box -from 8.0 -to 256.0 -increment 8  -borderwidth 10 -wrap on -textvariable no_of_pins

    set var1 $no_of_pins.get()
```

But I am not able to get the value in spinbox to var1 .
I am getting error like "0.get() extra tokens at the end of expression" when I access the var1 variable.
If I directly access the text variable no of pins , I am getting error as "cant read no_of_pins"

kindly help me in modifying my code

Answer (score 1):

The code to read the spinbox value should be just `set var1 $no_of_pins`, the .get() looks like something that has crept in from another language altogether.